# How to display images from a database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My program needs to upload images, so an image (varchar) location is saved in a MySQL database. It's working so far.

Now I want to display images and this does not work. Here is the code:

```
include ('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $filetemp= $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    $filename= $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $filepath= "images/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$filepath);
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"insert into  images (image) value ('$filepath')");
    if($sql){
        echo "uploaded";
    }
    else{
        echo " not uploaded";
    }
}

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from images");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<img src=' images/".$row['image']."'>"; // the problem is here, its just displaying img icon, not actual image 
}   

?>
```

Comment: what is the value stored for `image` in the db? also, the path in the `img` tag has a leading space before ` images/`

Comment: this is the value that is saved in image column "images/download.jpg"

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens instead? Also, be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction :

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from images");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>"; // the problem is here, its just displaying img icon, not actual image 
}
```

Also you need to get the actual path via `__FILE__` in case if needed.

Answer (score 2):

remove `images` from image path, you already store this in `image` column in `images` table

```
echo "<img src='/".$row['image']."'>"; // the problem is here, its just displaying img icon, not actual image
```

Comment: echo "<img src='/".$row['image']."'>"; // your code had '/' 

below line is correct 
echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>";

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are adding images/ into the database then when you call the row to display the image you're adding images/ adding making it look in images/images/filename